# Is there a way to include Tomcat 6 catalina.out and localhost.log content in a webapp's log files?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm looking for a way to include Tomcat's catalina.out (console output) and localhost.log (server logging) contents in the log for a webapp that's running on Tomcat (call it Foo).   So the contents of /var/log/tomcat6/foo/foo.log would then include all logging from the Foo app, the Catalina app and any console output.

If possible, the catalina.out and localhost.log files would need to continue on as before, so the server/console output would be logged in two places.

Is this possible using the default Tomcat 6 logging setup or would Tomcat need to be reconfigured to use Log4J?

Comment: I dont think that you will be able to do so. I suspect that you would need to write a custom LogAppender.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you're right - it looks like we'll have to go with some kind of external log shipping solution.  Oh well.